# Quote from Chekhov about a person who does not answer a letter

Tags: quote-source, russian-language, anton-chekhov

On the Internet, one often comes across, in different versions, Chekhov's statement that a person who does not answer a letter is like a person who rejects a hand extended to him for a handshake.

Maybe someone has read all of Chekhov's letters and can suggest the source of the statement. Or is this statement a fabrication?

Comment: Can you point to an example of one of the Internet quotations?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I've seen similar quotes in Russian: "Не ответить на письмо — это все равно что не подать руки, когда вам протягивают руку". Translated into English, it will sound like this: "Not answering a letter is like not shaking hands when someone extends their hand to you."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mentioned in [Korney Chukovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korney_Chukovsky)'s diary [entry for Jan. 23, 1910](https://biography.wikireading.ru/hWBiDlOrHG?ysclid=lhul5er2lq346951672):

> Вас. Ив. Немирович-Данченко был у меня сегодня и рассказывал между
> прочим про Чехова; он встретился с Чеховым в Ницце: Чехов отвечал на
> все письма, какие только он получал.
>
> – Почему? – спросил Василий Иванович.
> – А видите ли, был у нас учитель в Таганроге, которого я очень любил, и
> однажды я протянул ему руку, а он (не заметил) и не ответил на
> рукопожатье. И мне так больно было.

> [Vas. Iv. Nemirovich-Danchenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Nemirovich-Danchenko) visited me today and told me, among
> other things, about Chekhov; he met Chekhov in Nice: Chekhov answered
> all the letters he received.
>
> – Why? Vasily Ivanovich asked.
>
> – But you see, we had a teacher in Taganrog, whom I loved very much,
> and one day I extended my hand to him, and he didn't notice and didn't respond to the handshake. And it hurt so much.